normalizer of a element and orbit of an element
Let us consider a group G acting on itself by conjugation
I know that
$G_s =C(s) $   where $G_s$ is stabilizer of $s\in G$ and $C(s)$  is centralizer of $s \in G$.
and we can prove the class equation of the form
$ |G| = \sum|O(s)| $ where $O(s)$ is orbit of $s\in G$.
we can also prove the class equation of the form $|G|= \sum \frac{|G|}{|N(s)|}$ where the sum runs over one element in each conjugate class.
where $N(s)$ is normalizer of $s\in G$.
My question is does orbit of an element and normalizer of a element are same or they just have same cardinality?
Sorry if its very basic .Also If you can please improve my question .
Thanks in advance !

No, they are not. The orbit stabilizer theorem tells us that $|O(s)|=|G|/|C(s)|$ (note that $C(s)=N(s)$), so if $|O(s)|\neq C(s)$ they cannot be the same. Another argument is that orbits usually aren't subgroups, whereas stabilizers are. As a concrete counterexample take any abelian group with more than 1 element.

@schiepy.thanks for your answer . from your answer ,under conjugacy group acting on itself, normalizer and stabilizer are same and centralizer and stabilizer are same does that mean all the three are same

Yes, they are the same in this case
